# How to disable firewalld and keep it that way?

Tags: fedora, iptables, firewalld

I have for a school project a simple architecture composed of 3 virtual machines which all run Fedora 24: one server, one client, and one router. I decided to use iptables over firewalld for the extensive use of DNAT/SNAT that I only knew how to manage well with iptables; therefore, I disabled firewalld, and enable iptables:

```
# dnf install iptables-services
# systemctl stop firewalld
# systemctl disable firewalld
# systemctl start iptables && systemctl start ip6tables
# systemctl enable iptables && systemctl enable ip6tables
```

I had a set of rules I saved through `# service iptables save` and it worked perfectly on my router.

I used the same method on my two other machines, server, and client, but the rules were not saved. After a bit of research, I realized that iptables.service does not start on boot; and I further noticed that firewalld did even though it was disabled as presented above.

Is there a particular reason why firewalld would start even though it is disabled? Here's what the status shows right after boot:

```
firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset : enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-01-22 23:52:34 PST; 15s ago
    Docs:  man:firewalld(1)
Main PID: 619 (firewalld)
   Tasks: 2 (list:512)
  CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
          └─619 /usr/bin/python3 -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid

Jan 22 23:52:33 public systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
Jan 22 23:52:34 public systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
```

On the other hand, here is iptables's:

```
iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: `dnf remove firewalld` should do the job

Comment: That did the job. iptables can now run. Thanks!

Comment: `systemctl disable SERVICE` doesn't completely disable the service.  Only `systemctl mask SERVICE` guarantees that the service will not start no matter what.  The `systemctl` manpage does a really bad job of explaining when this matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The safest way to get rid of `firewalld` is to remove it:

```
dnf remove firewalld
```

It is quite ok to do for virtual machines.

Comment: I had a similar issue with Fedora27 NetworkManager, so I removed NM.

Answer (score 5):

Mask and disable the `firewalld` service:

```
systemctl mask firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld
```

Answer (score 0):

you can turn it off using the following command:

`#chkconfig firewalld off`

then restart your machine and its done.

this way you will turn off the firewalld service from run levels so it wont get started when you boot the machine.

Comment: -1. Fedora 24 uses `systemd`.  If `systemctl disable` does not show any warning, but leaves the service enabled, it was a bug.  Did anyone test `chkconfig` as a workaround for this mysterious problem?